# ArcMap crashes when saving an existing project

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am having issues saving an existing project on ArcMap 10.3. After adding another layer to the project, whenever I try to save the project, the software crashes and asks if I would like to send an error report. I have reset my application data but the error still persists and all other projects have started behaving the same way.

Comment: Does it also crash when you use Save As or Save A Copy?  You can also run MXD Doctor and see if it brings up any particular issues.  Also, bumping your version to 10.4.1 may help as well.  A full ArcGIS reinstall may also be advised.

Comment: @Baltok I guess I will have to upgrade to version 10.4.1 first to see if the issue will be resolved after which I will know if an uninstalling the software is imminent.

Comment: Try using File>Save As. I had a similar issue where it held a copy of the map for no reason at all and then collapsed. File>Save as solved the problem for me.

Comment: @MDHald The crash error still persists even with this option!

Comment: I had this problem, but it was because I was using a third party extension that has expired. Once I turned off the extension, everything was okay.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your Computers ENvironment Path Variables and ensure that there is only 1 Python Path Variable. Sometimes multiple variables are added and it causes the software to crash.

You can delete the variable by navigating to Windows Explorer > Right-click Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables - keep a backup of the Value in a Word doc in case removing it causes other issues.

Comment: I have tried that but the error still persists.

Comment: Does this crash behavior persistent with other MXD's or is it just this one?

Comment: It is with all the MXDs, even when I open a blank project, added just a shapefile and tried to save the project, it didn't save the project.

Comment: Try a repair Install if that does not work uninstall/reinstall may work. Time consuming but should work. Or call ESRI and create a case with them but they will tell you the same thing.

Comment: The software is currently running on a student version license. Having to reinstall it will create problems with the license I suppose and for this reason, I am scared to uninstall it. As for the repair, I have tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: if you open task manager view your machines resources when trying to save the mxd (try saving one with data and try saving one with no data/blank/empty).  See if the resource usage spikes. Also what spec does the machine have that you're operating from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57345/discussion-between-akinology-and-joe).